# Gantt Chart Timeline Pixels

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, charts

Hello I have been trying to figure something out for a couple days, I'm hoping someone may be able to shed some light on the situation.

I've been trying to code out a learning project. The goal is basically a gantt chart where I'd like to plot some events on eventually.

I am drawing out the timeline on a canvas, right now I have the "Seconds" lines being drawn 50px apart, with 4 shorter lines between them representing 200ms spaces.`enter code here`

```js
var aTime = "00:1:00.0";
var h, m, s, ms, totalSeconds, thecanvas = null;

// within the loop at line 76 I'm trying ( i * secondsSpacing ) to get the X
//position to draw the lines for each second. 
//Why would this not drawing the lines 50 pixels apart?

var secondsSpaceing = 50; 
var spaceTime = 44;
var mousePositioning = { x:0, y:0};
var zoom1a = 1; 

function drawStroke(sX, sY, eX, eY, color) {
  thecontext.strokeStyle=color;
  thecontext.lineWidth=1;
  thecontext.beginPath();
  thecontext.moveTo(sX,sY);
  thecontext.lineTo(eX,eY);
  thecontext.stroke();
}
   
function secToMinSec(seconds) {
  var min = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
  var sec = Math.ceil(seconds % 60);
  sec = (sec < 10) ? "0" + sec : sec;
  return new Array(min, sec);
}

var mouseXY = function(eve) {
  if(!eve) var eve = window.event;
  var totalOffsetX = 0;
  var totalOffsetY = 0;
  var canvasX = 0;
  var canvasY = 0;
  var canvas = this;
  do{
  totalOffsetX += canvas.offsetLeft;
  totalOffsetY += canvas.offsetTop;
  }
    while(canvas = canvas.offsetParent)
      canvasX = eve.pageX - totalOffsetX;
      canvasY = eve.pageY - totalOffsetY;
  return {'x':canvasX, 'y':canvasY}
}

$(document).ready(function() {
     thecanvas = document.getElementById("thecanvas");
     thecontext = thecanvas.getContext("2d");
     HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.xy = mouseXY;
     $(thecanvas).mousemove(function(e) {
      mousePositioning = thecanvas.xy(e); 
   $("#output").html( "X = " + mousePositioning.x +
          "<br> Y = " + mousePositioning.y );
       });
  
  var splitTimeStrMS = aTime.split('.');
  var splitTimeStr = splitTimeStrMS[0].split(':');
    h = parseInt(splitTimeStr[0]);
    m = parseInt(splitTimeStr[1]);
    s = parseInt(splitTimeStr[2]);
    ms = parseFloat(splitTimeStrMS[1]);
    
  var X = 60;
  totalSeconds = (h * X * X) + (m * X) + s;
  var divided = Math.ceil(totalSeconds / zoom1a);
  var timeChartArray = new Array();
  for(var i = 0; i <= divided; i++) {
    timeChartArray.push(i * zoom1a);
  }

  var neededCanvasWidth = Math.ceil(timeChartArray.length * secondsSpaceing); 
  var timeStr = null;
  var lineColor = "#000000";

  if(neededCanvasWidth > ($("#thecanvas").attr("width"))) {
   $("#thecanvas").attr("width", neededCanvasWidth);
    thecontext.font="normal 12px Arial";
  thecontext.fillStyle = lineColor;
  
    for(var i = 0; i < timeChartArray.length; i++) {
      //draw the line
      var xline = parseFloat(i * secondsSpaceing);
      drawStroke(xline, 0, xline, 8, lineColor);
  
     //draw the time text
      var timeStr = secToMinSec( timeChartArray[i] );
      var timeFormatted = timeStr[0] + ":" + timeStr[1];
      var timeXpos = (xline - 10);
      if(timeFormatted != "0:00") {
       thecontext.fillText(timeFormatted, timeXpos,24);
      }
   }
  }
});
```

```css
#canvasOut {position:relative; width:100%;  width:700px; background:#222222; 
 overflow:visible; }
#thecanvas {position:relative; height:140px; background:#fff; }
```

```html
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="canvasOut">
<canvas width="200" id="thecanvas"></canvas>
</div>

<div id="output">

</div>
<div id="output2">

</div>
```

If you move the mouse over the one second mark, you will see it is at x:50, two second mark is x:100 but then the three second mark is x:149, the same pattern continues and I keep losing seconds.  By the fifth second, it should be at x:250 but its lost two seconds and is x:248.  I'm still trying to figure this out myself but hopeful someone can shed some light as it's becoming discouraging.  Thanks for reading.

**EDIT**:  the code snippet worked in the editor, but I noticed when I press the "Run snippet" button that it's not showing the mouse position as it did in the editor, and on jsFiddle.

Here is a link to the project on jsFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/4y0q2pdw/19/

Thanks again

Comment: I think that the ceil method in time values causes loss of ms.Try to work with float numbers

Comment: liontass thank you I will give this a try and post the result

Comment: The other solution that I am thinking is to re-initialize the time and the x  axis every 5 sec to the expect time

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by re-initializing the time.  I have been trying to work with float numbers and not been having any luck.. I have a new fiddle I cleaned it up a bit to just focus on this problem. https://jsfiddle.net/4y0q2pdw/19/ within the loop at line 76 I'm trying ( i * secondsSpacing ) to get the X position to draw the lines for each second. Why would this not drawing them 50 pixels apart?

Comment: disregard the new jsfiddle link, the snippet is working here on Stack Overflow now

Comment: To be clear I meant that the snippet shows the example of the problem. I'm still stuck on this.

Answer (score 0):

Check this.I saw that every 1 sec the function subtracted 4px. So I replace the

```
var xline = parseFloat(i * secondsSpaceing);
```

with the

```
 var xline =parseFloat((i * secondsSpaceing)+3.6*i);
```

Initially I set instead of 3.6 the integer 4 but the function added then 1 or 2px after the 8 seconds line.So to be more accurate I replace the 4 by 3.6 that is more accurate.

Comment: hey buddy I really appreciate your help.  Someone pointed out to me that I was adjusting the height in the css which was scaling the canvas and causing the problem! I took that out and it works perfect :D